# Convert a nested object into a array

Tags: c#, arrays, tree

I have a simple class with a tree structure like this

```
public class Item
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }  
}
```

with some sample data like this

```
//     [1]
//    / | \
//  [2][3][4]
//     / \
//    [5][6]

Item alt = new Item()
{
    ID = 1,
    Items = new List<Item>() {
    new Item() { ID = 2 }, new Item() {
        ID = 3, Items = new List<Item>() {
            new Item() { ID = 5 },
            new Item() { ID = 6 }
        }
    },
    new Item() { ID = 4 }
    }   
};
```

now I want to flatten the result into a array with all child nodes (except root node) to the end
expected result:

```
[2]
[3][5]
[3][6]
[4]
```

I've tried something like

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Item>> Flatten(Item alt)
{
    if (alt.Items != null)
        foreach (var altsub in alt.Items)
            yield return Flatten(altsub);
}
```

but that doesn't seem to work as expected. Any suggestions?

Comment: How deep can the tree go?

Comment: @mjwills the depth is n (unlimited)

Comment: Basically you want to do a breadth first iteration using Queue, then add the results to a list as you pop them off, convert to an array and your done

Comment: @Dr.Snail: your expected result contains duplicates (node 3 presents 2 times). Is this OK?

Comment: @Dennis yes, the result are all possible paths to the end

Comment: @Dr.Snail: in this case word "flatten" confuses me. Flatten, IMO, is to get flat sequence from graph or tree. But you say you want all possible paths, so, the result should be a sequences of paths (which is a sequence itself).

Comment: The expected result confuses me. What is supposed to be the index of the element N of the array? the property `ID`? If that id is 42, what should be in the indexes 0 to 41? Your array seems to be a (2d) jagged array. What if you have a N depth?

Comment: Also, you need to put an example of another level, otherwise there are multiple options. Let me know when you have updated with another level and linear results

Comment: A simpler implementation of your class is `public class Item : List<Item> { public int ID { get; set; } }`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Item>> Flatten(Item alt)
{
    IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Item>> Flatten(Item[] a)
    {
        if (a.Last().Items == null)
        {
            yield return a;
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var c in a.Last().Items)
                foreach (var x in Flatten(a.Concat(new [] { c }).ToArray()))
                    yield return x;
        }
    }

    if (alt.Items != null)
    {
        foreach (var c in alt.Items)
            foreach (var x in Flatten(new [] { c }))
                yield return x;
    }
}
```

Given your sample input you can run it like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(
    String.Join(
        Environment.NewLine,
        Flatten(alt).Select(xs =>
            String.Concat(xs.Select(x => $"[{x.ID}]")))));
```

That gives me:

```
[2]
[3][5]
[3][6]
[4]
```

Comment: you seem to be a senior developer - would you say that was easy or advanced to solve?

Comment: @Dr.Snail - I've done this kind of thing before. It wasn't hard to solve. I also code in Prolog for fun - and this had a Prolog-ish kind of bent to it.

Comment: Nice work, I had a solution with a stack on the run, but had to leave work, but this is much better +1